# Некорректное отображение фигур

Tags: javascript

Я пока только изучаю JavaScript и написал программу, которая должна выводить фигуру на экран и при клике на нее выводить время, через которое на нее нажали, и так раз за разом.

После клика на первую фигуру она исчезает, но потом появляется вторая поверх первой и с каждым нажатием они всё больше накладываются друг на друга, хотя, по задумке, та фигура, на которую нажали, должна совсем исчезнуть. Что необходимо сделать?

```js
var canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canv.getContext('2d');
var startTime = new Date().getTime();

///////////////////* Figures *///////////////////

var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 70) + 45,
  y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
  w = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 75,
  h = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 75,
  radius = Math.floor(Math.random() * 75),
  radiusX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 20,
  radiusY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 20;

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF".split('');
  var color = "#";
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
};



function rectangle() {
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
  ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
};

function circle() {
  ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(75, 75, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
};

function ellipse() {
  ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.ellipse(100, 100, radiusX, radiusY, 50, 0, 300, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
};

function triangle() {
  ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineTo(25, 100);
  ctx.lineTo(75, 100);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
};

function trapezoid() {
  var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 10,
    d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 10,
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 10,
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 10;
  console.log(c, d, j, i);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + c, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + d, y - j);
  ctx.lineTo(x - i, y - j);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
  ctx.fill();
};


function figures() {
  var div = document.getElementById('div');

  div.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 550) + "px";
  div.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1350) + "px";

  if (Math.random() < 0.2) {
    rectangle();
  } else if (Math.random() >= 0.2 && Math.random() < 0.4) {
    circle();
  } else if (Math.random() >= 0.4 && Math.random() < 0.6) {
    ellipse();
  } else if (Math.random() >= 0.6 && Math.random() < 0.8) {
    triangle();
  } else if (Math.random() >= 0.8 && Math.random() <= 1) {
    trapezoid();
  };

  div.style.display = "block";
  startTime = new Date().getTime();
};

setTimeout(figures, Math.random() * 1000);

div.onclick = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById('div');


  div.style.display = "none";
  var finishTime = new Date().getTime();
  var reactionTime = (finishTime - startTime) / 1000;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = reactionTime + " seconds."
  setTimeout(figures, Math.random() * 3000);
};
```

```css
#div {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h3>Time of reaction <span id="timer"></span></h3>
<div id="div">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Для начала вынесите результат `Math.random()` в переменную.

Comment: Вынес, но фигуры перестали меняться после нажатия

Comment: @Verese404 добавьте пример полностью, чтобы можно было воспроизвести

Comment: @АлександрСычёв добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После функции `trapezoid()` изменил код на этот и всё заработало как надо:

```
    function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * max + min);
    };
    
    function figures() {
      var div = document.getElementById('div');
    
      div.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 550) + "px";
      div.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1350) + "px";
    
      var shapes = [rectangle, circle, ellipse, triangle, trapezoid];
      var randomIndex = getRandomNumber(0, shapes.length);
      shapes[randomIndex]();
      
      div.style.display = "block";
      startTime = new Date().getTime();
    };
    
    setTimeout(figures, Math.random() * 1000);
    
    div.onclick = function() {
      var div = document.getElementById('div');
    
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
      div.style.display = "none";
      var finishTime = new Date().getTime();
      var reactionTime = (finishTime - startTime) / 1000;
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = reactionTime.toFixed(3) + " seconds."
      setTimeout(figures, Math.random() * 3000);
    };
```

Спасибо всем, кто помогал :)

Answer (score 1):

Вызывая `Math.random()`, вы каждый раз получаете разные числа. Вам же нужно получить одно случайное число.

Конструкция с `if...else if...else` слишком громоздкая. Ее можно заменить на вариант покрасивее.

Можно записать все функции отрисовки фигур в массив и получать оттуда элемент со случайным индексом.

```js
  /**
  * Эта функция вернет случайное число от min до max
  */
  function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max + min);
  };
  /**
  * Эта функция отрисует случайную фигуру
  */
  function getRandomShape() {
    var shapes = [rectangle, circle, ellipse, triangle, trapezoid]; // представим список всех фигур в виде массива
    var randomShapeIndex = getRandomNumber(0, shapes.length); // получим случайное число от 0 до кол-ва элементов в массиве shapes
    shapes[randomShapeIndex](); // обратимся к фигуре с полученным индексом и вызовем ее функцию отрисовки
  }
```

Я не знаю, что у вас происходит в функциях `rectangle`, `circle`, `ellipse`, `triangle`, `trapezoid`, но могу предположить, что в `div` добавляется та или иная фигура.

Вот, как это работает. Фигуры я рисовать не стал, вместо них текст с названием.

```js
(() => {
  function createShape(name) {
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.textContent = name;
    return container;
  };

  function circle() {
    return createShape('circle');
  };

  function ellipse() {
    return createShape('ellipse');
  };

  function triangle() {
    return createShape('triangle');
  };

  function trapezoid() {
    return createShape('trapezoid');
  };

  function rectangle() {
    return createShape('rectangle');
  };

  /** 
  * Уберем все document.getElementById из функций, достаточно найти их документе единожды
  * Запишем их в общей области видимости
  */
  var div = document.getElementById('div'); 
  var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
  
  var startTime = getCurrentTime();

  /**
   * Эта функция вернет случайное число от min до max
   */
  function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max + min);
  };

  /**
   * Получаем текущий timestamp
   */
  function getCurrentTime() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  }

  /**
   * Эта функция вернет случайную фигуру
   */
  function getRandomShape() {
    var shapes = [rectangle, circle, ellipse, triangle, trapezoid]; // представим список всех фигур в виде массива
    var randomShapeIndex = getRandomNumber(0, shapes.length); // получим случайное число от 0 до кол-ва фигур в массиве shapes
    return shapes[randomShapeIndex](); // обратимся к фигуре с полученным индексом и вызовем ее функцию отрисовки
  }

  function figures() {
    this.innerHTML = ''; // очистим блок в чьем контексте мы выполняем функцию
    var bounds = [20, 80]; // минимальное и максимальное значение границ, где может появиться кнопка
    [div.style.top, div.style.left] = [bounds, bounds].map(([min, max]) => getRandomNumber(min, max) + "%"); // устанавливаем случайные значения top и left от 20 до 80
    var shape = getRandomShape(); // получаем случайную фигуру
    this.append(shape); // добавляем ее в блок на который нужно нажать
    this.style.display = "block";
    startTime = getCurrentTime();
  };

  /**
   * Запускает отсчет со случайным таймером до вызова figures
   */
  function startRandomTimeout(max, block) {
    setTimeout(() => figures.call(block), getRandomNumber(0, max)); // figures вызываем в контексте block с помощью метода call, вдруг захочется добавить еще 1 кликабельный блок
  }

  div.onclick = function() {
    this.style.display = "none";
    var finishTime = getCurrentTime();
    var reactionTime = (finishTime - startTime) / 1000;
    timer.textContent = reactionTime + " seconds.";
    startRandomTimeout(3000, this);
  };

  startRandomTimeout(1000, div);
})();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

#div {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px dashed tomato;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">Catch Me!</div>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Я разбил ваш код на функции поменьше, стараясь придерживаться [принципа разделения ответственностей](https://vk.cc/cfJFEA).

#### UPD

Вариант с исполььзованием только `canvas`.

```js
(() => {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  [canvas.width, canvas.height] = [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight];
  document.body.append(canvas);
  clearCanvas();
  
  let startTime = getCurrentTime();

  /**
   * Эта функция вернет случайное число от min до max
   */
  function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max + min);
  };

  /**
   * Получаем текущий timestamp
   */
  function getCurrentTime() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  }
  
  function getRandomColor() {
    const letters = "0123456789ABCDEF".split('');
    let color = "#";
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
  };
  
  function getRandomPosition() {
    const boundBorder = 200;
    return [
      [boundBorder, canvas.width - boundBorder*2],
      [boundBorder, canvas.height - boundBorder*2]
    ].map(([min, max]) => getRandomNumber(min, max));
  }
  
  function rectangle() {
    ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
    const [x, y] = getRandomPosition();
    const [w, h] = [[20, 200], [20, 200]].map(([min, max]) => getRandomNumber(min, max));
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
  };
  
  function circle() {
    ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
    const path = new Path2D();
    const [x, y] = getRandomPosition();
    path.arc(x, y, getRandomNumber(20, 200), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke(path);
    ctx.fill(path);
  };
  
  function ellipse() {
    ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
    const path = new Path2D();
    const [radiusX, radiusY] = [
      getRandomNumber(20, 200),
      getRandomNumber(20, 200),
    ];
    const [x, y] = getRandomPosition();
    path.ellipse(x, y, radiusX, radiusY, 50, 0, 300, false);
    ctx.stroke(path);
    ctx.fill(path);
};

  function triangle() {
      ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
      const path = new Path2D();
      const [x, y] = getRandomPosition()
      path.moveTo(x, y);
      path.lineTo(x+25, y+100);
      path.lineTo(x+75, y+100);
      path.closePath();
      ctx.stroke(path);
      ctx.fill(path);
  };

  function trapezoid() {
    const [c, d, j, i] = Array(4).fill([10, 200]).map(([min, max]) => getRandomNumber(min, max));
    const path = new Path2D();
    const [x, y] = getRandomPosition();
      path.moveTo(x, y);
      path.lineTo(x+c, y);
      path.lineTo(x+d, y-j);
      path.lineTo(x-i, y-j);
      path.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
      ctx.stroke(path);
      ctx.fill(path);
  };
  
  function clearCanvas() {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, canvas.width, canvas.height);    
  }
  
  function clearTimer() {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, 20);    
  }
  
  function drawReactionTime() {
    clearTimer();
    const finishTime = getCurrentTime();
    const reactionTime = (finishTime - startTime) / 1000;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.font = "12px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(`Time of reaction: ${reactionTime} sec.`, 20, 20);
  }
  
  function drawShape() {
    const Shapes = [rectangle, circle, ellipse, triangle, trapezoid];
    const randomIndex = getRandomNumber(0, Shapes.length);
    Shapes[randomIndex]();
    startTime = getCurrentTime();
  }
  
  /**
  * Проверяем пиксель на закрашенность
  */
  function isPositionFilled(x, y) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if (ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data[i] < 255) return true; 
    }
    return false;
  }
  
    
  function startRandomTimeout(max) {
    setTimeout(drawShape, getRandomNumber(0, max));
  }
  
  canvas.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const { x, y } = event; 
    if (x <= 200) return;
    if (!isPositionFilled(x, y)) return;
    drawReactionTime();
    clearCanvas();
    startRandomTimeout(3000);
  });

  
  startRandomTimeout(1000);
})();
```

```css
body {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Есть неточности в функциях отрисовки, с ними разберетесь сами.)

Чтобы понять все моменты, рекомендую почитать данные топики на [learn.javacript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/):

- [Массивы](https://learn.javascript.ru/array)
- [Методы массивов](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods)
- [Методы объекта, "this"](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods)
- [Явное указание this: "call", "apply"](https://learn.javascript.ru/call-apply)
- [Деструктурирующее присваивание](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment)

Comment: Благодарю, конечно, за помощь, но я так и не смог понять где у меня был баг

Comment: @Verese404 в условиях ``if...else if...else``. Я же вроде все расписал. Вызывать ``Math.random()`` нужно только 1 раз,  записать ее в переменную и уже эту переменную сравнивать с 0.2 - 0.8.

Comment: В свой изначальный код я добавил функцию `getRandomNumber()` и вызов функции через массив, но мне это не сильно помогло. А суметь понять ваш код у меня не получается

Comment: @Verese404 что именно вам не понятно? Если фигуры все еще накладываются друг на друга, то скорее всего вы не очищате ``canvas`` перед отрисовкой новой фигуры. В обновленном варианте это делается в функции `clearCanvas()`.